# What data do I need to plot a BSFC map

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, combustion, modeling, simulation

I have an 4 stroke spark ignition engine simulator which takes user inputs and outputs performance data.

I need rpm, torque and brake specific fuel consumption (bsfc) to plot the bsfc map. I am able to plot torque and bsfc against rpm respectively without any problems.

Since a contour plot requires x(rpm), y(torque) and z(bsfc) where z is a function of x and y, how can I express bsfc in terms of rpm and torque or can I take advantage of the simulator to produce raw data required to plot the map saving me trouble in deriving the equation. If its the latter, how can I obtain bsfc data? What parameters should I change or keep constant?

Comment: Unless you change some other parameter (e.g. throttle position), you'll always get the same bsfc and torque at any given rpm from the simulation (no contour possible).

Comment: Does changing the intake pressure simulates changing the throttle position?

Comment: That would be similar and should get the variation that you need to produce a contour plot.  For a given RPM, throttle position (TP) will vary manifold air pressure (MAP) and that's what'll control power/BSFC.  The only difference here is that, for a given TP, MAP will change with RPM. Changing MAP should be close enough for your purposes, I think. I am a little surprised that your simulator doesn't include a throttle. It's a pretty important component of most spark ignition engines.

Comment: OK, that's a start. So I have a multiple curves on the torque and SFC graph for different pressure, then how would I translate them into a contour map? Say I'm plotting torque against rpm from 1000-6000rpm (at increments of 10rpm) with throttle wide open (ambient pressure) this graph would envelope the SFC contour. Since this graph has 500 points, I would need SFC data of 500x500? How would I get it? Plot SFC against rpm from 1000-6000rpm for pressure ranging from 100kpa-50kpa with decrement of 0.1 kpa? How would this then fit into the contour plot? Sorry, I don't know how to plot contour plot

Comment: yeah... how to contour plot is plot is going to be program specific and you don't seem to have a great handle on what a contour plot is.  They show variation of one variable (BSFC,z) in terms of two others (rpm, torque=x,y).  You'll have curves in x,y which correspond to constant values of z (like a map showing terrain).  Your program is going to need a list of the (x,y,z) points and then it'll generate the plot. It may also be necessary to interpolate onto a uniform grid of x,y. Really, take the time to go and understand contour plots first, then this'll make more sense.

Comment: I think I understand contour plot quite well. Given an equation for z in terms of x and y, I can plot them. The problem with this is I'm just using raw data hence I don't know what raw data I need to generate. I can't plot a contour plot with just a column of 500 z points (500x1).

Comment: Ok then. As I indicated, running many simulations a different TP or MAP will give you different values of BSFC (z) and torque (y)  across the range of RPM (x). Depending on the program that you're using to generate the plot, you might need to interpolate or something because the points may not (probably won't) be uniformly spaced, but that's pretty much all there is to it.